# C++ Struct internal declaration confusion?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I've come across a declaration inside a C++ Struct{..} that I've never seen before. 
Can anyone tell me what it means;

```
struct DerivedMesh {

char cd_flag;

void (*calcNormals)(DerivedMesh *dm); // <-- What is this?
```

It kind of looks like it's dereferencing a pointer called calcNormals, but that's all I can make out.

Comment: Looks like a function pointer to me, a pointer to a function that accepts a `DerivedMesh *dm` parameter, and returns void.

Comment: Relevant: [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: its function pointer - a pointer to hold the address of a function of certain signature

Answer (score 2):

This is a C syntax for declaring [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

In this particular example, `DerivedMesh` will have a member `calcNormals` that is a pointer to a function accepting single argument of type `DerivedMesh*`. It can be called like an ordinary function:

```
void foo(DerivedMesh* dm) { ... }

DerivedMesh dm;;
// Init members and set calcNormals to actual function
dm.cf_flag = whatever;
dm.calcNormals = foo;
dm.calcNormals(&dm); // calls foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
void (*calcNormals)(DerivedMesh *dm);
```

is class data member definition with name `calcNormals` that has type of pointer to function of type `void( DerivedMesh * )`